# hiding a spinner when the data table is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a spinner which I need to hide when the data table is loaded.

Here is the code.

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
            "paging" : true,
            "scrollX": true,
 "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                $("#event-buble").css({"display" : "none", "height":"0px", "padding-top":"0px"});
                alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
             },
});
```

However, though I ran the code, spinner doesn't disappear.both table and spinner are showing.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Look at the supported events for the DataTable: http://www.datatables.net/reference/event/ . Perhaps you wanted a listener for the `draw` event?

Comment: There's no `load` event fired in this case as you're not loading anything into that element. You should be using a callback on your data function.

Comment: My answer is not exactly what you ask, but I recommend not using `.show()` or `.hide()` jQuery methods. I recommend manipulating spinner class, e.g. `.addClass("loading")` and `.removeClass("loading")`. Then you can „style“ visibility (and a lot more) in CSS, e.g. `spinner {display:none} spinner.loading {display:block}`

Comment: @Mooseman, id is there. how to find whether load evnt is triggered?

Comment: @listan lee, I tried when datatable event 'draw.dt'. this works when I redraw the table.

Comment: @MaugLee, why don't you recomend using hide method?

Comment: @mankadanka It's nothing bad with it. Just CSS way looks more elegant and easier to maintain.

Comment: I tried with datatable Events. What I noticed that there is not any evnt before, init.dt. I need to hide the spinner before the table is loaded. Therfore, I think I need to find a solution from jquery events.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a listener to your table for the `draw` event:

```
$('#datatable')
    // init the datatable
    .dataTable({
        "paging" : true,
        "scrollX": true,
    })

    // listen for the draw event
    .on( 'draw.dt', function () {
        $("#bubble").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Are you loading the data via an AJAX request?